# Parse Issue expected identifier Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c

I am getting a parse issue expected identifier 
the line of code that I am getting an issue with is:

```
self.data = [[[RWTScaryBugData alloc]] initWithTitle: rating];
```

Comment: Xcode is a tool to let you control an editor, compiler, debugger, and other tools. Your problem has nothing to do with Xcode, it has to do with the code you wrote in Objective C. (You have not provided nearly enough information to get a helpful response though.)

Comment: Get rid of the extra pair of square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra pair square bracket. Just replace your code with the following:

```
self.data = [[RWTScaryBugData alloc] initWithTitle: rating];
```